# select where in( after using LISTAGG)

Tags: sql, oracle

i want run this sql from different tables in a oracle data base

**tabel A   "SHIPMENT_LINE"**

```
ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID    SHIP_LINE_ID
0                   SLM4298700
1                   SLM4286868
12                  SLM4162661
19                  SLM4162693
```

**tabel B ="pckwrk"**

```
SHIP_LINE_ID    WRKREF
SLM4298700  
SLM4286868  W00003HAEM
SLM4162661  W00003DRGM
SLM4162693  W00003DRHO
SLM4162693  W00003DRHP
```

**tabel C = "invdtl"**

```
WRKREF          SUBNUM
W00003DRHP  S00004979375
W00003DRHP  S00004979358
W00003DRHP  S00004979365
W00003HAEM  CTN2379829
W00003DRGM  S00004980093
W00003DRHO  S00004830248
W00003DRHP  S00004979369
W00003DRHP  S00004979346
W00003DRHP  S00004979333



   select a.ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID,a.SHIP_LINE_ID,a.wrkref,
                (CASE WHEN ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID>0  THEN 
                       (CASE WHEN INSTR(a.wrkref, ',', 1)=0 then  
                       (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref) subnum 
                       from invdtl 
                       where wrkref in  ( a.wrkref )) --a.wrkref = "W00003DRGM"
                       else
                       (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref)subnum 
                        from invdtl 
                       where wrkref in  (a.wrkref))                                
"a.wrkref  "W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP""
                      end)
                   else NULL
              end)SUBNUM
    from(select a.ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID,a.SHIP_LINE_ID,
           ( SELECT  LISTAGG(wrkref, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref)wrkref
             FROM pckwrk
             WHERE SHIP_LINE_ID =a.SHIP_LINE_ID AND PRTNUM NOT LIKE'KITPART'
             GROUP BY SHIP_LINE_ID) as wrkref

    from (select a.ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID,a.SHIP_LINE_ID
          from SHIPMENT_LINE a)a)a
```

**Result**

```
ORDERQTY_SHIP_ID   SHIP_LINE_ID  WRKREF                   SUBNUM
0              SLM4298700    NULL                     NULL
1              SLM4286868    W00003HAEM           CTN2379829
12             SLM4162661    W00003DRGM           S00004980093
19             SLM4162693    W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP  NULL
```

On this part of th sql `where a.wrkref=W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref)subnum from invdtl where wrkref in (a.wrkref))` is result `NULL` and not `S00004979333','S00004979346','S00004979358','S00004979365','‌​S00004979369','S0000‌​4979375` how can i ADD the singel quote at the begin and end of the valeue `a.wrkref`

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: if  valeue a.werkref  = W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP is the result NUll and not  S00004979333','S00004979346','S00004979358','S00004979365','S00004979369','S00004979375

Comment: Please expand your question.  How are not able to `run this sql from different tables in a oracle data base`?

Comment: on this part of th sql  where a.wrkref=W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP
     (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref)subnum 
                        from invdtl 
                       where wrkref in  (a.wrkref)) 
is result NULL  and not   S00004979333','S00004979346','S00004979358','S00004979365','S00004979369','S00004979375
how can i ADD the singel quote at the begin and end of the valeue  a.wrkref

Answer (score 0):

My  guess is you are trying to match a string to a substring using `in` predicate which can only succeed if expressions are equal. Try `like`, demo

```
select 1 from dual
where ''''||'W00003DRHO'',''W00003DRHP'||'''' like '%'''||'W00003DRHO'||'''%'
```

So replace `CASE WHEN INSTR(a.wrkref, ',', 1)=0 then ... end` with

```
(select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref) subnum 
 from invdtl 
 where  ''''+a.wrkref+'''' like '%'''||wrkref||'''%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (CASE WHEN INSTR(a.wrkref, ',', 1)=0 then  
                   (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref) subnum 
                   from invdtl 
                   where wrkref in  ( a.wrkref )) --a.wrkref = "W00003DRGM"
```

result =ok
                       else
                       (select LISTAGG(subnum, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wrkref)subnum 
                        from invdtl 
                       where wrkref in  (a.wrkref))
"a.wrkref  "W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP" result =NULL (i nwant to add ' for and after a.wrkref) to get  like 'W00003DRHO','W00003DRHP'
                      end)